# Tempo de abertura do Motor Primavera v.10

Tags: c#

Tendo estranhado o tempo de abertura do motor Primavera v10 nas soluções de extensibilidade que desenvolvemos (6 a 10 segundos, dependendo da máquina), efectuei um registo de debug onde detectei que, ao invocar a abertura do motor, o "resolver" das bibliotecas Primavera carrega, se não todas, quase todas as bibliotecas disponíveis na pasta "Apl" da aplicação durante a abertura do motor.

Na v9, na abertura do motor, apenas 2 (as necessárias) eram carregadas: Interop.ErpBS900 e Interop.StdBE900.

Abaixo deixo o código de abertura do motor e do resolver:

```
var stdBeTrans = new StdPlatBS100.StdPlatBS();
erpAdminEngine = new ErpBS100.ErpBS();
erpAdminEngine.AbrePRIEMPRE((Interop.StdBE900.EnumTipoPlataforma)ErpAPI.ErpPlatformType, ErpAPI.ErpUser, ErpAPI.ErpUserPassword, stdBeTrans, ErpAPI.ErpInstance);

...

private static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
     var assemblyName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);
     var assemblyFullName =
           System.IO.Path.Combine(
                    System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(SYSTEM_FILES_FOLDER),
                    ERP_FILES_FOLDER),
                    assemblyName.Name + ".dll");

     if (System.IO.File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
         return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
     else
         return null;
}
```

**EDIT:** Para quem interesse, após alguma pesquisa acabei por perceber, e aprender, que o carregamento das dependências via Reflection com `Assembly.LoadFile` analisa a biblioteca e provoca o carregamento de todas as suas dependências na `AppDomain` antes de serem necessárias. Como no âmbito do Primavera v.10 não creio haver necessidade de carregar bibliotecas com a mesma identidade de caminhos diferentes, a grande diferença para a alternativa, a solução passa por utilizar `Assembly.LoadFrom`. Esta alteração reduz o tempo consumido pelo "Resolver" sem comprometer a integração.

Posto isto, basta fazer a seguinte substituição no código acima:

```
     if (System.IO.File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
         return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFullName);
         //return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
     else
         return null;
```

Ainda assim, o tempo da primeira abertura do motor é comparativamente muito superior ao do Primavera v.9.

Comment: Faça sua edição virar uma resposta para sua pergunta. Você mesmo pode responder ela e marcar como aceita.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Não é possível fazer a comparação que refere, dado que as DLLs na versão 9 eram COM e nunca seriam "carregadas" da forma que está a observar.

A verdade é que praticamente todas as dlls do motor são carregadas ao fazer "New ErpBS", dado que este motor agrega todas as funcionalidades de todos os módulos, tanto na versão 9 como na versão 10, mas como a tecnologia que tem na versão 10 é .NET, esse evento resolver vai ter MUITO mais invocações, dado que as DLLs vb6 são "invisíveis" para esta tecnologia.

Na versão 9 apenas passam no resolver os "pontos de contacto" com a tecnologia COM (ou VB6), isto é, os interops, tal como refere.

Sobre os problemas de performance que refere, estes carecem de uma análise mais detalhada que poderá solicitar ao suporte da PRIMAVERA, no entanto deixo apenas uma sugestão:

- Antes de fazer o MotorLE.AbreEmpresaTrabalho, caso tenha uma plataforma aberta, associe-a ao motor (MotorLE.Plataforma = ...).

Evitará uma nova abertura e poupará alguns segundos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Acrescento que a questão da performance acontece tanto no meu como no código dos exemplos da Primavera, com ou sem abertura da plataforma antes da abertura de motor. Na mesma AppDomain só acontece na primeira abertura, não nas posteriores. Temos webservices para soluções de mobilidade e, neste contexto, cada vez que a AppPool criar uma AppDomain para responder a um pedido ao webservice todo o processo de carregamente das DLL vai ocorrer. Isto significa gastar menos de 1 segundo para 6 ou mais só para o "resolver". Noutros contextos é uma questão contornável.